# How to calculate effect size of Mann-Whitney U test with unequal sample sizes

Tags: python, statistics

I want to calculate the effect size of Mann-Whitney U test with unequal sample sizes.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats

np.random.seed(12345678)  #fix random seed to get the same result
n1 = 200  # size of first sample
n2 = 300  # size of second sample

rvs1 = stats.norm.rvs(size=n1, loc=0., scale=1)
rvs2 = stats.norm.rvs(size=n2, loc=0.5, scale=1.5)

print(stats.mannwhitneyu(rvs1, rvs2))
```

How should I do?
I know the effect size = statistic/sqrt(sample size), but I wonder whether this equation cannot be applied to the unequal sample sizes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effect_size

r = 1 – (2U)/(n1 n2) is the answer.