# How to find the effect size of Mann–Whitney U test between 2 samples in python?

Tags: python, scipy, statistics

I want to find the effect size of Mann–Whitney U test between 2 samples in python. I am currently use

```
males = [19, 22, 16, 29, 24]
females = [20, 11, 17, 12]

from scipy.stats import mannwhitneyu
U1, p = mannwhitneyu(males, females)
```

But this only gives me test statistics for sample x and p_value. I think I need standardized test statistics to calculate effect size. How do I find the effect size? Thank you!

Comment: The formula for effect size varies a lot but it is usually defined as nth percentile of sample distribution minus nth percentile of null distribution  over nth percentile of null distribution . The nth percentile can be any percentile. 50th percentile or the median is common.

Comment: I found this, do you think this is correct? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58890724/how-to-calculate-effect-size-of-mann-whitney-u-test-with-unequal-sample-sizes

Comment: The wiki link in that answer is a good start.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effect_size. You choose an formula for effect size based on your two random variables and what do you want to investigate.